# Imitating Obj-C block behaviour with C++ lambdas

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, lambda, block

Is it possible to use C++ lambdas in the same way that Objective-C blocks are used?

Take, for example, the following Objective-C code:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
// ...
- (void)myMethodWithBlockParam:(void(^)(void))block;
//
@end
```

The message would be sent as follows:

```
[myClassInstance myMethodWithBlockParam:^{
     // Do something inside block
}];
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect in C++ with lambdas?

Comment: @JoergB has shown you the syntax in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ you can do

```
struct MyClass {
  void myMethodWithBlockParam(std::function<void()> block);
};
```

This would be called with a lambda as

```
myClassInstance.myMethodWithBlockParam([]()->void {
   // Do something inside block
});
```

This readily expands to functions with parameters and return type. Using a specialization of std::function as function parameter type allows anything that is callable with the specified signature to be passed (functions, function objects, lambdas).

Lambdas also can be closures, i.e. bind variables from their definition context by reference or by value (as a copy).

Comment: Using `std::function<>` as your argument type has the added benefit of letting callers pass function pointers and function objects too.

Comment: +1 That's really nifty! Does anyone know if there are any majorly different semantics between Objective-C blocks and C++ lambdas (except for the way variables are captured)?

Comment: @dreamlax: The only things I can think of: 1) Variables captured by C++ lambdas must be declared explicitly or have a default capturing mode specified. No such need for blocks. 2) C++ lambdas can capture variables by value or by reference as specified in the capturing syntax. Blocks capture by value by default, but if a variable is declared as `__block`, it is captured by reference, in a way that guarantees that it is valid as long as the block is valid, unlike in C++. 3) Variables captured by value in blocks cannot be assigned to, unlike the ability to declare the lambda as `mutable` in C++.